# count returning the size of the first cell in the array and not the size of the entire array

Tags: php

I have an array `$all_orders` which contains arrays, the $temp_array contains every iteration after explode a string composed of `8` words, and `$handle` is composed of `3 lines` in the file:

```
while(!feof($handle))
{
  $order=fgets($handle);
  $temp_array=explode(",",$order);
  array_push($all_orders,$temp_array);
}
```

Now when i try to count the `$all_orders` array elements (which is supposed to be 3), i get simply 8:

```
echo count($all_orders);// display 8
```

why didn't i get 3 ?

**EDIT:**

Here is the result i got when trying to print to content of the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => chaine.com
            [3] => chaine
            [4] => chaine
            [5] => chaine
            [6] => chaine
            [7] => chaine

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => chaine@fudd.com
            [3] => chaine.
            [4] => chaine
            [5] => chaine
            [6] => chaine
            [7] => chaine

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] =>

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
            [2] => chaine@bunny.com
            [3] => chaine.
            [4] => chaine
            [5] => chaine
            [6] => chaine
            [7] => chaine

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
        )

)
```

Comment: You should `var_dump($all_orders)` and you will probably see why. No-one here can really tell you without seeing the file - although from the code above, you would only get 8 if the file described by `$handle` had 8 lines in it, or if `$all_orders` already had some elements before you started reading it. And you can shorten the entire contents of that loop to `$all_orders[] = fgetcsv($handle);`

Comment: The txt file contains exactly 3 lines

Comment: can you add print_r($all_orders); before the echo and show us the result

Comment: i work in the command line, i couldn't copy and paste the result, but, your suggestion show me 8 cells in the array with some cells like this: `[0]=>Array([0]=>)`. This is shown for 5 cells, that's why i keep getting 8 as the size of the array, but this is weird.

Comment: @Malek It contains exactly 3 lines *of data* - does it contain any blank lines? What do you see if you `var_dump($all_orders);`? You can copy/paste it here by dumping the output to a file, append `> temp.txt` to the end of your command, and copy/paste the contents of the `temp.txt` file that will created here.

Comment: @redmoon7777: i have edited my post, that what i got when i try to print the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one of two problems:

- Your file has some blanks lines in it
- PHP is getting confused by the style of the line endings (such as `\r\n` on a platform that just uses `\n`)

Regardless of what the problem actually is, this should fix it:

```
while(!feof($handle)) {
  // Evaluating the trimmed line as a bool will effectively skip blank lines
  if (!trim($order = fgets($handle))) continue;
  $all_orders[] = explode(',', $order);
}
```

Comment: Thanx man, this fixed it, can you explain me what continue is for?  anyway, thanx a lot for help, that work like a sharm.

Comment: The `continue` happens when the result of `trim(fgets())` evaluates to `FALSE`. So realistically this is going to be blank lines (empty string), or if `fgets()` returns `FALSE` - although it will also cause a problem if you file contains a line which is just `0` - just that character. It just skips to the next iteration so that `$all_orders` is not affected by blank lines.

Comment: If you want to skip the first line, to be on the safe side I would do `$loop = TRUE; while ($loop) if (trim(fgets($handle))) $loop = FALSE;` before the main loop. This keeps calling `fgets()` until it finds a line that has data, then breaks - so when you reach the main loop, the first line will have effectively been skipped.

Comment: Note from [manual page for `fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php): `If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.`