# errors when command line programming

Tags: php, command-line

when i try to process a file with command line :

```
cat texte.txt|php index.php
```

i got this weird stack:

```
C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention>cat texte.txt|php index.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 92
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 92


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 94
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 94


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 96
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 96


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 98
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 98


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 100
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 10
0

Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 102
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 10
2

Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 7 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 104
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 10
4

Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 92
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 92


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 94
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 94


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 96
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 96


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 98
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 98


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 100
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 10
0

Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 102
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 10
2

Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 7 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 104
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 10
4

Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 92
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 92


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 94
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 94


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 96
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 96


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 98
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 98


Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 100
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 10
0

Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 102
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 10
2

Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 7 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on li
ne 104
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php on line 10
4

Call Stack:
    0.0005     330608   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Fraud Prevention\index.php:0
```

**EDIT:**

here is my code between the 92 and 104 line:

```
    $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");

    $N = $title = fgets($handle, 1024);


    while(!feof($handle))
    {
      if (!$order = fgets($handle)) continue;
      $all_orders[] = explode(',', $order);

    }

    foreach ($all_orders as &$order){

    $order["Order id"]=$order[0];
    unset($order[0]);
    $order["Deal id"]=$order[1];
    unset($order[1]);
    $order["Email address"]=$order[2];
    unset($order[2]);
    $order["Street address"]=$order[3];
    unset($order[3]);
    $order["City"]=$order[4];
    unset($order[4]);
    $order["State"]=$order[5];
    unset($order[5]);
    $order["Zip Code"]=$order[6];
    unset($order[6]);
    $order["Credit Card"]=$order[7];
    unset($order[7]);

    }

print_r($all_orders);
```

Comment: What's in index.php, line 92-104? You're accessing array items that don't exists.

Comment: I have updated my code, there is a snippet from line 92 to 104 of my code, i don't know, but it worked fine hour ago, i didn't changed anything.

Comment: @Malek Your missing the `trim()` off the `fgets()` call - I'm guessing you've got some of those empty items that you were getting [a few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777059)... `var_dump($all_orders)` to confirm ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In your foreach loop you are accessing array values without checking if they even exist.

PHP gives you a notice every time you're accessing a non-existent index - and in your case, a stack trace (I'm assuming it's XDebug). A notice is not a showstopper mistake, your script simply goes on, and gets another notice, and another, and so forth.

You can check an index' existance with `isset($order[$index])`.

Also, your seem to be reading CSV data. How about using php's built-in [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/fgetcsv) that already handles many edge cases your code doesn't?

And by the way, your `foreach` loop is unneccesary, you could be doing that processing in the while loop, after you read a record.

Comment: I have already suggested `fgetcsv()` but the OP seems to have a problem with line endings with this particular file that was causing `fgets()` to return blank lines for every other record. He is missing a `trim()` from some code I gave him before which is probably giving him empty records again - [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777059).